# How to convert the numbers stored as text type into number type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I am working with a dataframe (*257673 rows × 44 columns*) where the requirement is to convert the numbers(float or integers) which are stored as text type into number type.

I cannot individually check each of the columns and identify those numbers and convert the type manually.

Is there any way to do such?

Here is the data sample:

```
          id       dur  spkts  dpkts  sbytes  dbytes      rate  sttl  dttl  \
73261  73262  0.819105     10      6     534     268  18.31267   254   252   

             sload        dload  sloss  dloss     sinpkt      dinpkt  \
73261  4697.810059  2187.753662      2      1  90.966778  140.124406   

              sjit        djit  swin       stcpb       dtcpb  dwin    tcprtt  \
73261  5374.348957  246.231375   255  1762162911  2604383089   255  0.193588   

         synack    ackdat  smean  dmean  trans_depth  response_body_len  \
73261  0.118476  0.075112     53     45            0                  0   

       ct_srv_src  ct_state_ttl  ct_dst_ltm  ct_src_dport_ltm  \
73261           9             1           2                 2   

       ct_dst_sport_ltm  ct_dst_src_ltm  is_ftp_login  ct_ftp_cmd  \
73261                 1               5             0           0   

       ct_flw_http_mthd  ct_src_ltm  ct_srv_dst  is_sm_ips_ports  label  \
73261                 0           2           5                0      1   

       proto_3pc  proto_a/n  proto_aes-sp3-d  proto_any  proto_argus  \
73261          0          0                0          0            0   

       proto_aris  proto_arp  proto_ax.25  proto_bbn-rcc  proto_bna  \
73261           0          0            0              0          0   

       proto_br-sat-mon  proto_cbt  proto_cftp  proto_chaos  \
73261                 0          0           0            0   

       proto_compaq-peer  proto_cphb  proto_cpnx  proto_crtp  proto_crudp  \
73261                  0           0           0           0            0   

       proto_dcn  proto_ddp  proto_ddx  proto_dgp  proto_egp  proto_eigrp  \
73261          0          0          0          0          0            0   

       proto_emcon  proto_encap  proto_etherip  proto_fc  proto_fire  \
73261            0            0              0         0           0   

       proto_ggp  proto_gmtp  proto_gre  proto_hmp  proto_i-nlsp  proto_iatp  \
73261          0           0          0          0             0           0   

       proto_ib  proto_icmp  proto_idpr  proto_idpr-cmtp  proto_idrp  \
73261         0           0           0                0           0   

       proto_ifmp  proto_igmp  proto_igp  proto_il  proto_ip  proto_ipcomp  \
73261           0           0          0         0         0             0   

       proto_ipcv  proto_ipip  proto_iplt  proto_ipnip  proto_ippc  \
73261           0           0           0            0           0   

       proto_ipv6  proto_ipv6-frag  proto_ipv6-no  proto_ipv6-opts  \
73261           0                0              0                0   

       proto_ipv6-route  proto_ipx-n-ip  proto_irtp  proto_isis  proto_iso-ip  \
73261                 0               0           0           0             0   

       proto_iso-tp4  proto_kryptolan  proto_l2tp  proto_larp  proto_leaf-1  \
73261              0                0           0           0             0   

       proto_leaf-2  proto_merit-inp  proto_mfe-nsp  proto_mhrp  proto_micp  \
73261             0                0              0           0           0   

       proto_mobile  proto_mtp  proto_mux  proto_narp  proto_netblt  \
73261             0          0          0           0             0   

       proto_nsfnet-igp  proto_nvp  proto_ospf  proto_pgm  proto_pim  \
73261                 0          0           0          0          0   

       proto_pipe  proto_pnni  proto_pri-enc  proto_prm  proto_ptp  proto_pup  \
73261           0           0              0          0          0          0   

       proto_pvp  proto_qnx  proto_rdp  proto_rsvp  proto_rtp  proto_rvd  \
73261          0          0          0           0          0          0   

       proto_sat-expak  proto_sat-mon  proto_sccopmce  proto_scps  proto_sctp  \
73261                0              0               0           0           0   

       proto_sdrp  proto_secure-vmtp  proto_sep  proto_skip  proto_sm  \
73261           0                  0          0           0         0   

       proto_smp  proto_snp  proto_sprite-rpc  proto_sps  proto_srp  \
73261          0          0                 0          0          0   

       proto_st2  proto_stp  proto_sun-nd  proto_swipe  proto_tcf  proto_tcp  \
73261          0          0             0            0          0          1   

       proto_tlsp  proto_tp++  proto_trunk-1  proto_trunk-2  proto_ttp  \
73261           0           0              0              0          0   

       proto_udp  proto_unas  proto_uti  proto_vines  proto_visa  proto_vmtp  \
73261          0           0          0            0           0           0   

       proto_vrrp  proto_wb-expak  proto_wb-mon  proto_wsn  proto_xnet  \
73261           0               0             0          0           0   

       proto_xns-idp  proto_xtp  proto_zero  state_acc  state_clo  state_con  \
73261              0          0           0          0          0          0   

       state_eco  state_fin  state_int  state_no  state_par  state_req  \
73261          0          1          0         0          0          0   

       state_rst  state_urn  service_-  service_dhcp  service_dns  \
73261          0          0          1             0            0   

       service_ftp  service_ftp-data  service_http  service_irc  service_pop3  \
73261            0                 0             0            0             0   

       service_radius  service_smtp  service_snmp  service_ssh  service_ssl  
73261               0             0             0            0            0
```

​

Comment: `df.astype(float)` ?

Comment: will it convert types of all data to float?

Comment: Yes, it will, as long as they are convertible (look like numbers).

Comment: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'udp' ` showing this error.

Comment: I think df.astype(float) converts all the values present in the dataframe to float. I am originally looking for a way to check if the type of data matches the type it is officially assigned to. If the data is a number but its been assigned as a text/string type, seeing that the program will change the datatype to number type which can be either float or integer.

Comment: Just as I said: "as long as they are convertible." "udp" is not convertible. You should post a data sample to get a better answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.